# CGAffineTransformRotate - jump before animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to create an animation rotate image in the button, but the image is jumping before animation, that is, turns 180 degrees and begins the animation

My code:

```
@IBAction func switchListButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1) {
        self.switchListButton.imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate((self.switchListButton.imageView?.transform)!, CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
    }
}
```

I really can't work out why this is happening?

Help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
self.switchListButton.imageView!.clipsToBounds = false;
self.switchListButton.imageView!.contentMode = .Center;

UIView.animateWithDuration(1) {

    self.switchListButton.imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate((self.switchListButton.imageView?.transform)!, CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
}
```

Though not completely sure, I guess image below could illustrate why the code above work. You can see that when you rotate a UIView, the bounds of the view could change and exceed its parent view (above red line in below image), so if you set `clipToBounds` to true, the transform could fail.

[image]